# Create a boot disk which can be SSH-ed into via WiFi

Tags: wifi, ssh, sd-card, vnc, pi-3

I've got a new pi 3. I haven't got a spare monitor or keyboard, so I was wondering...

Is it possible to create an SD card bootable OS (noobs, raspian, ubuntu etc) which can be connected using wifi via SSH? So I could connect to the pi from a iOS terminal app (and eventually using VNC)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question you asked; Yes it is possible. Raspbian and Ubuntu are not TOO dificult, if you have a Linux machine. NOOBS is quite difficult. I think iOS just adds another level of difficulty.

I strongly suggest you borrow a monitor and keyboard for initial setup. Rather than suggesting the many options (which you will find discussed on this site) you need to specify what you have.